# Cloud Functions: Mongoose aggregate search causing Error: Collection method aggregate is synchronous error

Tags: flutter, mongoose, google-cloud-functions

I am calling a Cloud Function call from my Flutter app when it starts. When I start from 'flutter run', my function call returns `Error: Collection method aggregate is synchronous`.

But, when I refresh the app, with `command + r`, then it returns the correct value.

app.dart

```
  var gameFunction = await functions.httpsCallable('gameS').call({
     'gamingId': 'afijeoaijosf'
  });
```

f function index

```
export const gameS = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    try {
      return await gameFunctionF(data, context);
    } catch (err) {
      const aa = err as functions.https.HttpsError;
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(aa.code, aa.message, aa.details);
    }
  });
```

f function gameFunctionF

```
export async function gameFunctionF(data: any, context: CallableContext) {
  console.log(data);
  try {
    return await db
    .aggregate([
      { $project: { game_profile: 1} },
    ])
    .toArray();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`aaaa - err - ${err}`);
    throw 'nooooo';
  }
}
```

When I start the app, I get that `Collection method aggregate is synchronous` error. But then when I refresh the app with `command + r`, it returns the data that I want. No variable has been changed no nothing. `var gameFunction` runs when the app.dart is called.

I really don't get why it is happening since it only causes this error when I start from `flutter run` but it works fine when I just refresh the app.

I'd tried with my android phone that it causes the error when i open the app after I terminate the app as well.

Comment: The error seems to be with the way mongoose connects to the database. You may refer to a similar [Stackoverflow case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69953709/error-collection-method-aggregate-is-synchronous) which is having the similar error. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: dang. cheers brother. I was assuming that too. But, did not quite sure what I could do. I was looking at the AWS mongoose method but then it wasn't that different as what I have done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mousumi suggested to look at, that link solved the problem for me.

```
const mongoConn = createConnection();
export const mongooooooo = mongoConn.openUri(
  `uri`,
  {
    connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
  }
);
```

This is how I changed from `createConnection(uri)`. And then, you have to adjust the db function to

```
(await db)
    .aggregate([
      { $project: { game_profile: 1} },
    ])
```

The error has been solved! Thank you to Mousumi!

UPDATE ---------

I had to add `await` in front of `(await db)` in order to get the promise result.

```
await (await db)
    .aggregate([
      { $project: { game_profile: 1} },
    ])
```